# Java JTree expand only level one nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree

With a JTree, assuming the root node is level 0 and there may be up to 5 levels below the root, how can I easily expand all the level 1 nodes so that all level 1 & 2 branches and leafs are visible but levels 3 and below aren't?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for the quick response guys. However I have now found the simple solution I was looking for.  For some reason I just couldn't see DefaultMutableTreeNode.getLevel() in the JavaDocs!  FYI what I'm doing now is:

```java
DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = treeTop.getNextNode();
do {
    if (currentNode.getLevel() == 1) 
        myTree.expandPath(new TreePath(currentNode.getPath()));
    currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
} while (currentNode != null);
```

Comment: That is a good solution too: +1. You can accept your own solution if you want (and put it at the top of the answers), but know that you will not gain any rep point.

Answer (score 3):

You have some Tree utility classes out there which do precisely that:

Like [this one](http://www.koders.com/java/fid73C19EA27E58706B007DAAF35EE56BF2AE0F3D8B.aspx?s=jtree+expand+level#L3):

```
public class SimpleNavigatorTreeUtil {

   /**
    * Expands/Collapse specified tree to a certain level.
    * 
    * @param tree jtree to expand to a certain level
    * @param level the level of expansion
    */
   public static void expandOrCollapsToLevel(JTree tree, TreePath treePath,int level,boolean expand) {
      try {
         expandOrCollapsePath(tree,treePath,level,0,expand);
      }catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
         //do nothing
      }
   }

   public static void expandOrCollapsePath (JTree tree,TreePath treePath,int level,int currentLevel,boolean expand) {
//      System.err.println("Exp level "+currentLevel+", exp="+expand);
      if (expand && level<=currentLevel && level>0) return;

      TreeNode treeNode = ( TreeNode ) treePath.getLastPathComponent();
      TreeModel treeModel=tree.getModel();
      if ( treeModel.getChildCount(treeNode) >= 0 ) {
         for ( int i = 0; i < treeModel.getChildCount(treeNode); i++  ) {
            TreeNode n = ( TreeNode )treeModel.getChild(treeNode, i);
            TreePath path = treePath.pathByAddingChild( n );
            expandOrCollapsePath(tree,path,level,currentLevel+1,expand);
         }
         if (!expand && currentLevel<level) return;
      }      
      if (expand) {
         tree.expandPath( treePath );
//         System.err.println("Path expanded at level "+currentLevel+"-"+treePath);
      } else {
         tree.collapsePath(treePath);
//         System.err.println("Path collapsed at level "+currentLevel+"-"+treePath);
      }
   }


}
```

---

Basically, you need to explore the sub-nodes until your criteria (here the depth level) is met, and expand all nodes until that point.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for first level children.
To expand ALL children replace .children() with .breadthFirstEnumeration()

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JTree tree = new JTree();
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        JButton btn = new JButton("Press Me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                for (Enumeration e = ((TreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).children();e.hasMoreElements();) {
                    TreeNode tn = (TreeNode)e.nextElement();
                    tree.expandPath(new TreePath(((DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel()).getPathToRoot(tn)));
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING!** `children()` get you only one level of children. You need `breadthFirstEnumeration()`. Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

As your level 1 nodes are all children of the root node, and assuming that you are using `DefaultMutableTreeNode` (needed for the call to `getPath()`), you can just iterate over the root node's children like so:

```
Enumeration<?> topLevelNodes
    = ((TreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).children();
while(topLevelNodes.hasMoreElements()) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node
        = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)topLevelNodes.nextElement();
    tree.expandPath(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [expand(TreePath)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#expandPath(javax.swing.tree.TreePath)) for all level-2 nodes.

Comment: yes obviously, but how would I iterate through all the nodes knowing which ones are level 2?

Comment: You can do it the way you’ve already done it but you should already have the information in your data model.